# Dynamically write to output buffers/columns in SSIS script component

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm using a script component that deserializes a JSON file as a source in the dataflow of my SSIS package. The JSON file is a list of nested objects. I've made outputs in the script component for each type of object in the nested JSON. The outputs and the classes in the actual script share the same name. One of the nested objects (the most granular data) called "Specification" can be one of over 25 unique class models. All these objects have a "type" field that I can use to determine which object to deserialize the json to. My problem is then dynamically getting these objects and their field values to the outputbuffers and their columns. Is there a way to dynamically use the type of object to specify which outputbuffer to add a row to? And is there a way to cycle through the properties of my deserialized object and assign those values to the outputbuffer columns?

Something along the lines of this based on having already deserialized to a specification object model:

```
foreach(var spec in Specifications) 
{
    var bufferOutput = $"{spec.type}Buffer";
    var bufferType = Type.GetType(bufferOutput);
    var bufferMethod = bufferType.GetMethod("AddRow");
    bufferMethod.Invoke(bufferType, null);


    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in spec.GetProperties())
    {
        var name = propertyInfo.Name;
        var bufferColumn = buffertype.GetProperty("name");
        bufferColumn.SetValue(propertyInfo.GetValue(null), null)
    }
}
```

Here is a boiled down example of what the json looks like:

```
[
    {
        "full name": "Penny Ortiz",
        "foundation": [
            {
                "Technical Name": "Air Products & Chemicals",
                "Specification": [
                    {
                        "Type": "GlobalTacticsManager",
                        "examplefield": 70
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "GlobalTacticsManager",
                        "examplefield": 69
                    }
                ],
                "Kategori": "velit occ"
            },
            {
                "Technical Name": "Commercial Metals",
                "Specification": [
                    {
                        "Type": "DistrictSecurityDeveloper",
                        "examplefield": 73,
                        "examplefield2": "sdfafag",
                        "examplefield3": "tytytytyt",
                        "examplefield6": 24.5
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "DistrictSecurityDeveloper",
                        "examplefield": 43,
                        "examplefield2": "dfasoafd"
                    }
                ],
                "Kategori": "commodo commod"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My only other option seems to be a switch case based on "type" and manually writing lines for the hundres of different variables between the classes. Any suggestions on a better approach are appreciated.

I've tried the above code with no results per the dataviewer I have setup between the script source and the OLE DB destination. So far as I know debugging within the actual script itself is not possible, so it feels like a bit of a black box. If there are any suggestions for debugging I would be grateful to hear them.

Comment: It sounds like you might be open to considering other options. So how do you feel about 1) code generators to automate "writing lines for the hundreds of different variables between the classes", or 2) ditching SSIS and picking a different technology (maybe .NET) to do this, because debugging hundreds of switch options in SSIS is daunting, at best.

Comment: @tgolisch Yeah, I've considered both options. Currently the client is requesting an SSIS package so I wanted to check if there were any options for achieving this via Reflection or something before I start using code generators (or try convincing the client to use another technology)

Comment: SQL server does have JSON columns too. So maybe you could put the asymmetric data into a JSON column, or maybe use a stored procedure to handle it (generate an openquey statement or something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working through a similar problem and have found a solution that is working. (I would love to hear any suggested improvements though).

I think that the magic bit of code you are looking for is:

```
typeof(Output0Buffer).GetProperty(<buffer column name>).SetValue(Output0Buffer,<value for field>);
```

In my case, I have a SQL config table that stores the object field list and data type. I retrieve this earlier in the SSIS package and pass it as a variable to the script component, then store it in a list of the custom type `BufferField`. (`BufferName` may not be needed, but since the `BufferWrapper` strips underscores this was handy, and is just `Name.replace("_","")`).

When the script reads through the JSON file, it stores each field in a dictionary called `returnValues`. The final result looks like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

    class BufferField
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string BufferName { get; set; }
        public string dataType { get; set; }
    }

    List<BufferField> writeList = new List<BufferField>();

    /* Populate writeList */

    Dictionary<string, string> returnValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    /* Populate returnValues and execute below code inside same row level loop*/

    Output0Buffer.AddRow();
    foreach(BufferField field in writeList)
    {

        if(returnValues.ContainsKey(field.Name))
        {

          // all stored in dictionary as string, convert if not string in buffer
          if(field.dataType == "bool")
          {
            typeof(Output0Buffer).GetProperty(field.BufferName).SetValue(Output0Buffer, bool.Parse(returnValues[field.Name]));
          }
          else if (field.dataType == "DateTime")
          {
                typeof(Output0Buffer).GetProperty(field.BufferName).SetValue(Output0Buffer, DateTime.Parse(returnValues[field.Name]));
          }
          else if (field.dataType == "decimal")
          {
                typeof(Output0Buffer).GetProperty(field.BufferName).SetValue(Output0Buffer, decimal.Parse(returnValues[field.Name]));
          }
          else if (field.dataType == "double")
          {
                typeof(Output0Buffer).GetProperty(field.BufferName).SetValue(Output0Buffer, double.Parse(returnValues[field.Name]));
          }
          else if (field.dataType == "int")
          {
                typeof(Output0Buffer).GetProperty(field.BufferName).SetValue(Output0Buffer, int.Parse(returnValues[field.Name]));
          }
          else if (field.dataType == "long")
          {
                typeof(Output0Buffer).GetProperty(field.BufferName).SetValue(Output0Buffer, long.Parse(returnValues[field.Name]));
          }
          else
          {
                typeof(Output0Buffer).GetProperty(field.BufferName).SetValue(Output0Buffer, returnValues[field.Name]);
          }

       }
       else
       {
            // if no value retrieved from the Json, then write as null
            string isNull = field.BufferName + "_IsNull";
            typeof(Output0Buffer).GetProperty(isNull).SetValue(Output0Buffer, true);
       }
   }
returnValues.Clear();
```

DON'T forget the clear.

In my case, we also needed to create a custom field list for each output buffer, and found that a PowerShell against the `.dtsx` file works for this. I can share if needed, but I believe it is unnecessary for your use case.

Comment: Sorry for extremely delayed response. I ended up convincing the client to shift over to an EF Core solution for this project. But if ever in the future I use another SSIS solution this is a great fix! Thanks so much for your answer :)